About a double integral
I try to use walfram mathematica to compute a double integral,
my code is
Integrate[0.5*exp[-90*(x - 0.5)^2 - 45*(y + 0.1)^4] + exp[-45*(x + 0.4)^2 - 60*(y - 0.5)^2], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]

while the output is just a simplify, not a result.
Then I try to use walfram alpha online with the same code, but it gives the anwser.
I'm really confused!


Mathematica functions start with capital letter, chnage exp ->Exp
Rationalize the integrand before using symbolic Integrate
Integrate[Rationalize[0.5*Exp[-90*(x - 0.5)^2 - 45*(y + 0.1)^4] + 
Exp[-45*(x + 0.4)^2 - 60*(y - 0.5)^2]], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}] 
%//N (*0.125844*) 

NIntegrate[ 0.5*Exp[-90*(x - 0.5)^2 - 45*(y + 0.1)^4] + 
Exp[-45*(x + 0.4)^2 - 60*(y - 0.5)^2] , {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}] 
(*0.125844*)


Thanks! The change of code is right. But I have done a numerical computation, it seems 0.125844 is the right result, not 0.06046...I'm confused again...

See my update...
